# Is it possible to create a view of Nodequeues

Tags: views, nodes

I'm trying to create a list of all my nodequeues using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), To be clear I'm not trying to create a view that showing the content within a Nodequeues, but rather create a views that lists the Nodequeues themselves is this possible? if so how do do it?

Comment: Click "Add View", choose "Nodequeue", profit...

Comment: @Clive I do not se an option for nodequeue when I create a new view, either under Show or Of type ... I am using nodeque 7.x-2.0-beta1 nad views 7.x-3.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create listing of all nodequeues with views I would have [exposed](http://www.sitepoint.com/exposing-tables-views-drupal-7/) nodequeue_queue table to views.

Comment: so this would require a separate module?

Comment: Yes, but there is not much you can do by exposing table to view, except of the fact that now views can list all nodequeues, if that is the use case you should probably look into nodequeues api functions (http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!nodequeue!nodequeue.module/7) and the function you may need is http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21nodequeue%21nodequeue.module/function/nodequeue_get_all_queues/7

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from the [Community Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/293117) of [Nodequeue](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodequeue) (about "**Automatic Creation of Views**"):

> When configuring Nodequeue, you can opt to "Automatically create one view per queue" (you may wish to leave this off if you plan to create the views yourself).
>
> The views created automatically cannot be deleted from the Views interface because they are implemented "in code". However, if you disable the auto-creation, then clear caches, these views will be removed.
>
> **It is highly recommended that you use the Views module to display your subqueues.** However, if you choose not to, you can alternatively use a small PHP snippet.
>
> To use nodequeue from Views (D7), add a 'relationship' to the queue, and typically set to 'require this relationship'. Optionally add 'nodequeue: Position' to match the preset queue order.

Comment: I think perhaps you are misunderstanding what I am trying to do, I don't want to create a view of the content within a nodequeue, I already know how to do that, I'm looking to create a view that list all of the nodequeues like the one that is on the nodequeue page it's self

Comment: Hm, THAT is the real question (sorry I did not read it like so). Please EDIT your question to include that clarification (I will consider editing my answer also then), ok?

Comment: Yeas, sorry that was unclear, I edited the content of the question, although I left the title, because I think that technically I am asking for " a view of nodeques" and not a "view of content within a nodequeue"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible to get Views to list queues as such. But here's something I did to achieve a similar result, that is: a view that lists queues.

I created a new content type (called "collection" in my case) with a field for nodequeue ID. This allowed me to add a description, author, and other metadata that Nodequeue doesn't do. For individual colelction display, I created a view of the queue's content attached to the node by way of the ID. Then I made a view that showed collections, which effectively lists the queues. (In fact I made another queue to curate the collections and my view displayed that meta queue.)

I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score -1):

Steps to make a view from node queue:

1. Create a node queue and add some article(content) to it.
2. Create a view and select fields in format section show (fields).
3. Click on Add relationship in advance section.
4. search for Node-queue and add the relationship.
5. check the Require this relationship checkbox, 
   check the Limit to one or more queues (recommended) checkbox and Select the node-queue name which you have created earlier and hit apply button.
6. Now in fields section just add the field you want from you node queue content and Only the article(content) added to the node queue content will get appear in display of view.

[image: Please find attachment of configuration of relationship.]

Comment: i'm trying to create a list of the the nodequeues them selfs and not the content within them